# Why does TypeScript still think my variable assignment may be null

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to use a type with nullable members to extend another type who's members are never null.

If I do this:

```js
type Foo = {
    a: string | null
    b: string | null
}

type Bar = {
    a: string
    b: string
    c: string
}

const foo: Foo = {
    a: 'A',
    b: 'B',
}

const bar: Bar = {
    ...foo,
    c: 'C',
}
```

TypeScript will complain, telling me that 'Type null is not assignable to type string' with reference to the 'bar' variable. Saying that 'a' and 'b' are possibly null.

I would have thought that since the assignment too 'foo' has no nulls, the bar assignment can't have any null values either.

In my use case, both 'foo' and 'bar' are part of a test and I'm testing the path in which foo's properties are not null. I could remove the 'Foo' annotation and this would work but I want help in my editor while writing the test. Also, if I add to the 'Foo' or 'Bar' types later, I want typescript to tell me as my tests are compiled, instead of my tests failing or, worse, not failing. Is something like this possible or am I going about this in the wrong way?

Comment: If `foo` will not change, it may be better to define the properties explicitly, or not type it at all and let its type be inferred, as when you specify the type in this way then Typescript will be wary, as you _may_ at some point add a property with `null` as the value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend introducing a helper function which verifies that `foo` is of type `Foo` without widening it to `Foo` and forgetting about the non-null-ness of its properties.  Example:

```
type Foo = {
  a: string | null;
  b: string | null;
};

type Bar = {
  a: string;
  b: string;
  c: string;
};

// helper function
const verifyType = <T>() => <U extends T>(u: U) => u;

const foo = verifyType<Foo>()({
  a: "A",
  b: "B"
});

const bar: Bar = {
  ...foo, // no error now
  c: "C"
};
```

Calling `verifyType<Foo>()` returns a function that takes one argument of type `U` that must be *assignable to* `Foo` and returns it as `U` (without widening it to `Foo`).  If the argument is not assignable to `Foo`, you get an error:

```
const fooBad = verifyType<Foo>()({
  a: 1, // error! number not assignable to string | null
  b: "B"
});
```

Note that the `verifyType` function circumvents the [excess property checks](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks) for fresh object literals, so it will allow extra properties:

```
const fooAllowExtraProp = verifyType<Foo>()({
  a: "A",
  b: "B",
  x: "extra" // no error
});
```

If you want to forbid extra properties, you can change the helper function to be less accepting of its argument by forcing `U` to extend `Foo & Record<Exclude<keyof U, keyof Foo>, never>`, meaning that if `U` has any extra keys (`Exclude<keyof U, keyof Foo>` is not empty) the properties at those keys must be of type `never` (which will exclude just about anything you throw at it):

```
const verifyExactType = <T>() => <
  U extends T & Record<Exclude<keyof U, keyof T>, never>
>(
  u: U
) => u;

const fooForbidExtraProp = verifyExactType<Foo>()({
  a: "A",
  b: "B",
  x: "extra" // error!, string not assignable to never
});
```

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKBvAUFKBDAXFAZ2ACcBLAOwHMoAfKcgVwBsmBuTKAI3yLKtvrM26AL7t0oSFABC2YsjQc8hEhUrss3FX3UcAxj1VV2Y9Oj1xyRKADcIZAGYgAKuGgoAPM4B8ACgCUyN5QHgCqUBAAHsAQ5AAmBFA+vgz4oYFIwQziFlbAUA4ICnaOLm4e8HB+-r4YWMoARACCDQA0HFoN0g2i-jmW1pxy+LLyKHVQAHTThXCtUAD0C-SI9sRw8uRwAO76+A0Awj2m5gP5s7JxxfakTq6QFQjVtUr4AIzzSxHE68QAhIIALacewrfLYAgEUiUcjYThMaDARC8NQCRgsDr7bq9fp5AoIJosHYAUWixGwAAV1mBrqV7hBHlUAi96vsWu1NFi2hxIvsoiRsA1Fsstt9fjizLlrCVbiBSdg9MB6QovNUgiEOOF+bEEkkoAAyKAAJQgFmIcQ8pL0TAYcQZAGsICA4A4oKF5o7na6fPNyBASt50H4OKk3egMllcdZZvBiJxSHFSQKqXAaSgZU55Yr6YznhNGuzMVAutysLzi-zyUKvmsNn95ij+FtwZDobD4YjEH6ShL0EA)

Comment: verifyExactType is precisely what I was looking for and since I'm very weak on generics, I would NEVER have come up with that on my own.

Answer (score 3):

I think that the compiler is not looking at the assignments but rather at the type declarations.

On the other hand, you're mixing apples and oranges by going with `...foo`. I'd rewrite this like this, which also, as a side effect, removes the error you have:

```
interface Foo {
    a: string | null
    b: string | null
}

interface Bar extends Foo {
    c: string
}

const foo: Foo = {
    a: 'A',
    b: 'B',
}

const bar: Bar = {
   ...foo,
   c: 'C',
}
```

But on the other hand, if `Foo` and `Bar` are not related at all and you need this just for the intelisense, I'd keep what you already have and just add `...foo as any` inside `bar`.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are explicitly telling him the type of foo to be Foo. You have to remove the type annotation so typescript will infer the type.

Think of `type Foo = {a: string | null, b: string | null}` like a base type. The infered type of  `{a: 'A', b: 'B'}` is `{a: 'A', b: 'B'}` (no typo, it's actually the type). This implicitly implements the type `Foo`. 
By using `const foo:Foo = ...` You tell Typescript that the right side must implement `Foo` - it can be any of its implementations (implicit or explicit).

Comment: That is exactly what I did to get by this and move on. But now, if I extend the 'Foo' type later, my tests will never know about it and compile just fine. They may fail or not. I loose all type safety on Foo.